# Linq2Sql Repository pattern

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Does anyone know where can I find an easy example of Linq2SQL wrapped in the repository pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the link:
http://geekswithblogs.net/AndrewSiemer/archive/2008/02/05/linq-to-sql---implementing-the-repository-pattern.aspx

Comment: This is precise and easy. I went for this because of having less to learn more on Repository pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out

http://multitierlinqtosql.codeplex.com/

http://goneale.com/2009/07/27/linq-to-sql-generic-repository/

Comment: I recommend the second article. Worked like a charm for me.

Comment: Anyone have a mirror for the goneale.com link?

Answer (score 0):

Check this blog post : http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/02/19/100-unit-testable-linq-to-sql-repository.aspx
There is a zip linked to it with a working demo.

Answer (score 0):

One more is AcroDB: http://oleksiy.pro/tag/acrodb/

The project is used on the first layer after Linq2SQL, and makes entities as abstract as interfaces, and at runtime on project start dynamic entities are generated.